# chroot fails to be executed more than once in a while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, chroot

## Description

Very same loop containing `chroot` command can be executed in terminal but can not be executed within a shell script.

## Reproduction

1. Create a basic (or copy of your) rootfs in `/mnt/myrootfs`
2. Create a file in `/mnt/myrootfs/tmp/hello.sh` (and make it executable) with the following contents:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "i am exiting."
   exit
   ```
3. Create the following script (`./chroot-poll.sh`):

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   while sleep 1; do 
       echo "chrooting into the target..."
       sleep 1    
       sudo chroot /mnt/myrootfs /bin/bash --rcfile /tmp/hello.sh
   done
   ```

## Result

Console output is as follows:

```
$ ./chroot-poll.sh 
chrooting into the target...
i am exiting
chrooting into the target...

[1]+  Stopped                 ./chroot-poll.sh
```

Why is this stopping? Bringing it foreground by `fg` makes it iterate once more, and it stops again.

## Running within a terminal works:

Copying the contents of `./chroot-poll.sh` and pasting directly into the terminal works as expected:

```
$ while sleep 1; do      echo "chrooting into the target...";     sleep 1    ;     sudo chroot /mnt/myrootfs /bin/bash --rcfile /tmp/hello.sh; done
chrooting into the target...
i am exiting
chrooting into the target...
i am exiting
chrooting into the target...
i am exiting
chrooting into the target...
i am exiting
chrooting into the target...
^C
```

## Question

Why contents of a script can work in a terminal while script itself fails to execute?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)` on Slackware -current. When I run `./chroot-poll.sh` it runs continuously

Comment: I can still reproduce the same problem with `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. My target rootfs that I'm `chroot`ing is Debian 10 Buster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something that I can't quite get to add up about this question and I believe it has something to do with the text:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 ./chroot-poll.sh
```

I've only every seen text like that when running a process in the background yet there's no `&` anywhere in the the question and you've not mentioned running the job in the background.  As others note I can't reproduce your error *except* if I run the script in the background.

When I try running your script with `./chroot-poll.sh &` rather than just `./chroot-poll.sh` I get similar results to you, so I can only assume you are running it in the background.

Usually a job goes into `Stopped` when it is running in the background and attempts to read from the stdin.  The very simple workaround for this can be to make it read from `/dev/null` instead:

```
./chroot-poll.sh < /dev/null
```

That way when anything attempts to read, it will read from `/dev/null` and not from stdin.

---

I believe this is ultimately happening because you are running bash in interactive mode.  You are not asking it to execute a script, only override the `~/.bashrc`.  Despite the `exit` bash is still reading from stdin as if it expects you to type something at the prompt.  To get bash to read the script as a script use:

```
sudo chroot /mnt/myrootfs /bin/bash -f /tmp/hello.sh
```

Comment: `./chroot-poll.sh < /dev/null` makes the `chrooting into the target...` appear continuously, so I would assume the `/tmp/hello.sh` script runs continuously. However, when I add the `echo $(($(</tmp/count) + 1)) > /tmp/count` line to the `/tmp/hello.sh`,  `./chroot-poll.sh < /dev/null` stops after first iteration, leaving `/tmp/count` with content of `1`. I also couldn't get how `-f` switch helps here.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't replace `--rcfile` with `-f`, I only added `-f` switch. Now I issued the command exactly you specified and it works as expected.